# Default file hierarchy for juju created instances

Tags: juju, wordpress

What is the default file hierarchy for juju created instances? For instance, on a wordpress install, where would the wp-content folder show up? It doesn't seem to be in /var/www.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not specified by juju; it's up to the charm authors to put things in sensible places.

In the case of wordpress, in particular, `/var/www` *will* eventually be populated... but the authors chose to delay doing so until the service has joined a relation with a database (such as mysql), because that's the first point at which they can actually serve anything useful.